# Use dependency of java 1.8 project in java 1.7 project

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project build on java 7 say A.
I have a another external maven project build on java 8 say B.

Is it possible to add dependency of project B in project A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's is not possible as the classes in project B (when compiled with Java 8) will have a different class format. The result will be some type of class format error [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030725/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-com-mysite-folders-folders-unsupported).

If project B is compiled with target `1.7` **and** uses no API from Java 8 then it is possible that it will work.

The safest thing is to assume that you have to use Java 8 when using project B.

Comment: *@Uwe Plonus*  thanks for quick response.I am able to compile project A with dependency of projet B, but i am getting error of **java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError** when running unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Usually not, but it depends on what APIs project B uses.